# Can I use a WrapPanel to organize ListView group headers?

Tags: c#, wpf, containers, wrappanel

I would like to be able to use a WrapPanel to wrap by group header instead of by item.

I have implemented the following ICollectionView `view` for a ListView bound to an ObservableCollection `studentlist`:

```
        view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(studentlist);
        view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("sectionoutput"));
        view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("sectionoutput", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("displayname", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

The XAML includes a style resource to set the template for the group header:

```
    <Style x:Key="ContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                        <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" IsExpanded="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource expanderconverter}}">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This Style is used as the GroupStyle for the ListView:

```
    <ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">            
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
...
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding displayname}">
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

As is, the code presents a vertical list of student names grouped by a header listing their section number.  But I would like to list the groups sequentially in a horizontal direction.

I know that I am able to organize the items in the ListView with a WrapPanel:

```
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ItemWidth="150">                        
                </WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

But this code merely displays the students in a group side by side rather than displaying the groups themselves side by side. What I would like to do is have the groups themselves wrapped horizontally.  I've tried to implement a wrap panel in the style resource, but I haven't been successful and have been wondering if there is a way to wrap by group.

I figure it is possible to do this by switching to a TreeView and turning the groups into Items.  But I would prefer to use a ListView if at all possible because my program implements a class that takes the ListView as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GroupStyle` has a `Panel` property that you can set to an `ItemsPanelTemplate` with a `WrapPanel`:

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}">
        <GroupStyle.Panel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.Panel>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I tried doing something like this, but my syntax was wrong.  I'm still new to WPF, but I really like its data binding features.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose to have a `ViewModel` that is the DataContext of the XAML posted below that contains an `ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel>` named `GroupsViewModel`.

`GroupViewModel` merely has a property named `GroupName` that is the name of the Group to show and it has a property of `ObservableCollection<StudentViewModel>`.

`StudentViewModel` has the property `displayName` to display the name of the Student.

Said so, by using an `Expander` and 2 nested `ListBox` you can get what you asked, like the following code:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding GroupsViewModel}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Expander HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsExpanded="True" Header="{Binding GroupName}">
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding StudentViewModel}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding displayname}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                </ListBox>
            </Expander>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```